# Getting Error - Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: php, mysql

I created a new database, created a user and granted all access to this user. But when I am trying to set password for `localhost`. I'm getting error -

```
Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Here's what I am doing in php code -

```
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$ThisDBName."",$con1) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON ".$ThisDBName.".* to  ".$ThisDBUserName." identified by '".$ThisDBPassword."'",$con1) or die(mysql_error());
```

I searched for this error and tried using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` before `SET PASSWORD`

```
mysql_query("FLUSH PRIVILEGES",$con1) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("SET PASSWORD FOR " . $ThisDBUserName ." @'localhost' = PASSWORD(".$ThisDBPassword.")",$con1) or die(mysql_error());
```

But still I'm getting the same error and can not connect using `mysql_connect()`.

I also tried answers of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877458/mysql-error-1133-cant-find-any-matching-row-in-the-user-table) but that too doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you can't connect using `mysql_` have you tried `mysqli_`? Plus, what type of webserver are you running?

Comment: what is the point of `.""` in `mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$ThisDBName."",$con1)`?

Comment: An why you do separate `set password` when you just set password with `grant`?

Comment: @Fred-ii-Yes I tried using msqli_ but getting same problem - 'Access denied for user'. I am using xampp localhost.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I used `set password` to set the password for `loaclhost`. Because when i was trying to connect to database using `mysql_connect()` i was getting error -` Access denied for user 'mydb_11161'@'localhost'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GRANT` is mising host mask. This should allow your user from any host:

```
mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON ".$ThisDBName.".* to "
              .$ThisDBUserName."@'%' identified by '"
              .$ThisDBPassword."'",$con1) or die(mysql_error());
```

See GRANT syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

Comment: I tried above but couldn't connect to database. Getting the same problen - `Access denied for user 'mydb_11170'@'localhost'`